# Appropiate way to set a tableviews datasource and delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

Ok, so I have tableview controller 1. Inside of tableview controller 1's didSelectRowAtIndexPathMethod, I attempt to call a popOver with a table view depending upon if the data warrants one, which looks like so:

```
UIViewController *popoverContent=[[UIViewController alloc] init];
        UITableView *tableView=[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(265, 680, 0, 0)    style:UITableViewStylePlain];

    UIView *popoverView=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 300)];

    popoverView.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];


    FirstTVController * firstTV = [[FirstTVController alloc]init];

   // popOver.keyId = model.key_id;
    popoverContent.view=popoverView;
    popoverContent.contentSizeForViewInPopover=CGSizeMake(200, 420);

    [tableView setDelegate:firstTV];
    [tableView setDataSource:firstTV];

    popoverContent.view=tableView; //Adding tableView to popover

    UIPopoverController *popoverController=[[UIPopoverController alloc]    initWithContentViewController:popoverContent];
    [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(340, 400, 0, 0) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft animated:YES];
```

Now when I change the tableview data source and delegate to self it works. But I'm puzzled by when I set table view data source and delegate methods, I get a   **return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class])); EXC_BAD_ACCESS** What am I doing wrong here?

```
@interface FirstTVController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
```

Answer (score 0):

`firstTV` goes out of scope at the end of this method. So the table view's data source and delegate properties point to an invalid object.

You have to possible options:

1. Make `firstTV` an instance variable so it doesn't go out of scope.
2. The much better approach is to clean up all of the code in your question by using a custom class extending `UITableViewController`. There's no reason to create a generic `UIViewController`, add your own table view to it, and then use yet another class as the table's data source and delegate. Roll all of that into a single class.